# How to fix running total in DAX not working with date slicer

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

I'm new to PowerBI and still learning and have been working on this for days with no luck. Would really appreciate any help.

I'm trying to get the running total to adjust based on the start and end dates on the date slicer.

My Dates table looks like below and continues to add a date each day.

Date Table:

[image: Date Table]

I also have a Spent table that just has the date and the amount spent that goes on till April 2023 and has values, even though the initial values show 0.

Spent Table:

[image: Spent Table]

I created a one-to-many relationship from the date table to the spent table

Table Relationship:

[image: Table Relationship]

I created two measures in the Spent Table

```
    Sum of Amount = CALCULATE(SUM(Spent[Amount]))
    
    Running Total of Amount =
    CALCULATE(
    SUM(Spent[Amount]),
    FILTER(
    ALLSELECTED(Dates),
                Dates[Dates] <= MAX(Dates[Dates]) &&
                Dates[Dates] >= MIN(Dates[Dates])
            )
        )
```

I've also tried the following measure

```
    Running Total of Amount =
    
    VAR MinDate = CALCULATE(MIN(Dates[Dates]),ALLSELECTED(Dates[Dates]))
    
    VAR MaxDate = CALCULATE(MAX(Dates[Dates]),ALLSELECTED(Dates[Dates]))
    
    VAR DatesToUse = FILTER (
    
    ALL(Dates),
    
    CalendarDates[Dates] >= MinDate
    
    && CalendarDates[Dates] <= MaxDate
    
    )
    
    RETURN
    
    CALCULATE(
    
    [Sum of Amount],
    
    DatesToUse
    
    )
```

When I put it in a table, this is what I get:

Result Matrix:

[image: Result Matrix]

The Sum of Amount measure is working correctly but the Running Total Measure always equals the Sum of Amount measure for some reason. I've tried many variations of the measure and they all lead to the same thing.

The correct table should look like this:

| FiscalYearAdjusted | Sum of Amount | Running Total of Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 3,047,586.92 | 3,047,586.92 |
| 2023 | 12,391,657.45 | 15,439,244.37 |

I'm not even sure if I'm close with my DAX Code.

Please help! I have no idea how to fix this...

Trying to have it so that the running total adjusts as I adjust the slicer for max and min dates.